# Loading a .NET assembly from a byte array

Tags: arrays, powershell, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm getting this error when I try to load a program in memory

error:

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v2.0.50727
```

here my code:

```
$Path = "D:\calc.exe"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path)

$string = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

$bytees = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($string)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytees)
```

Comment: That's not an error message.  `.exe` is also not an assembly.

Comment: Good point re error message, @Maximilian, but note that `*.exe` files can be assemblies too. In fact, any .NET-compiled console application is an assembly (whether or not it exports _public_ types).

Comment: @mklemento I wasn't aware the .NET ecosystem also allowed combined bin/lib results. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3):

As [Maximilian Burszley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/maximilian-burszley) points out, **what you're seeing is *not* an *error***.

In fact, it indicates that **your assembly was *successfully* loaded from your byte array**:

The [`System.Reflection.Assembly.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.Load) method returns a [`System.Reflection.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly) instance representing the loaded assembly, and since you're not assigning that return value to a variable, PowerShell implicitly prints a friendly representation of the object *to the console*, and this is what you're seeing; if you append `| Format-List` to your `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytees)` call, you'll see more detailed information about the newly loaded assembly.

**Any public types defined in the assembly should now be available in your PowerShell session**; however, given that you're indicating an `*.exe` files as the source, **perhaps you want to execute the assembly as you would the original executable, possibly with command-line arguments**.

To provide a full example:

```
# Note: This must be an executable or DLL compiled for .NET
$Path = "D:\calc.exe"

# Get Base64-encoded representation of the bytes that make up the assembly.
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path)
$string = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

# ...

# Convert the Base64-encoded string back to a byte array, load
# the byte array as an assembly, and save the object representing the
# loaded assembly for later use.
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($string)
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)


# Get the static method that is the executable's entry point.
# Note: 
#   * Assumes 'Program' as the class name, 
#     and a static method named 'Main' as the entry point.
#   * Should there be several classes by that name, the *first* 
#     - public or non-public - type returned is used.
#     If you know the desired type's namespace, use, e.g.
#     $assembly.GetType('MyNameSpace.Program').GetMethod(...)
$entryPointMethod = 
 $assembly.GetTypes().Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Program' }, 'First').
   GetMethod('Main', [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static, Public, NonPublic')

# Now you can call the entry point.
# This example passes two arguments, 'foo' and 'bar'
$entryPointMethod.Invoke($null, (, [string[]] ('foo', 'bar')))
```

Note: A ***generalization* of the above** - which doesn't require you to know the *class* name and invokes the CLI entry point *without arguments* - can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74512389/45375).